# Exibir popup ao fechar página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup

Olá. Gostaria de saber um código para exibir um formulário como popup quando o usuário for fechar a página. Ou seja, aquele momento em que ele leva o cursor para cima do navegador. Pois a página foi feita pela ferramenta RD.

**Formulário em questão:**
https://forms.rdstation.com.br/formulario-071734d1611046a89c8d

**Código do formulário:**

```
<div id="formulario-071734d1611046a89c8d"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/rdstation-forms/stable/rdstation-forms.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new RDStationForms('formulario-071734d1611046a89c8d-html', 'UA-11653131074-1').createForm();
</script>
```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento `mouseleave` no objeto `document`.

Esse evento é disparado toda vez que um usuário deixa uma área, nesse caso, a área do site.

```js
new RDStationForms('formulario-071734d1611046a89c8d-html', 'UA-113131074-1').createForm();

document.onmouseleave = function() {
  console.log("oushe");
  document.querySelector("#overlay").style.setProperty("display", "flex", "important")
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  display: none !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/rdstation-forms/stable/rdstation-forms.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlay">
  <div id="formulario-071734d1611046a89c8d"></div>
</div>

Insira o cursor aqui
```

Você também pode utilizar o evento `beforeunload`. Ele será disparado quando o navegador tiver prestes a fechar toda a página.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Já vai sair?";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
  return confirmationMessage;
});
```

> O erro que aparece é problema no JavaScript externo.

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir. Respondi em baixo pois não consegui formatar corretamente.

Comment: @Maicon atualizei minha resposta. Adicionei um exemplo com o formulário.

Comment: Ótimo @Valdeir. Veja como ficou.. http://materiais.financiatudo.com.br/teste. Apenas na minha página a popup não aparece como sobreposição com botão de fechar. Você consegue me ajudar com isso?

Comment: @Maicon editei minha resposta. Adicionei o `position` no CSS e alterei de `block` para `flex` ao levar o cursor para fora da página.